# How to hide a data inside a jquery datatables bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-modal

I have used the bootstrap4 modal popup plugin to display the data modal popup, now I want to hide a single row from the modal popup.What should I do to hide a row.
[Image For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4UPs.png)

```
"responsive": {
            "details": {
                "display": $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                    "header": function (row) {
                        var data = row.data();
                        return 'Details of ' + data.employeeName;
                    }
                }),
                "renderer": $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll()
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you give source code to display modal?

Comment: I have updated the code used to display the bootstrap modal popup , I have used the bootstrap modal popup plugin to display the data inside popup

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Is it Datatable? If true, i think you can use custom renderer. I just see it at https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.renderer